How to reorder my Excel tables so they are in alpha/numeric order by table name
I am trying to modify the order in which tables appear on my Excel worksheets. Please note that this refers solely to tables, not to table names or anything else.
I have several worksheets that each have several tables on them. These are the standard Excel tables that one can create using CTRL+T or by using the "Format as Table" functions on the Home tab of the ribbon.
I recently changed the various table names from letters to numbers. I now need the tables to show on each page in numerical order by those new numerical names.
Can anyone please advise if Excel has an existing capability that allows a user to resort the order in which the tables described above appear on the worksheet on which they reside? I know that I can do this manually, but am hoping that there is a time-saving, existing Excel capability to do this for me.
Again, I am asking about the order of the tables on their worksheet. I am not asking anything about the table names. Neither I am asking how to resort the contents of any table.

The only way I can think of getting something like this done is with VBA, and you'd need to run the macro everytime you rename a table.

Regarding your edit, the answer is No, Excel does not have anything built-in which can sort the order that the tables appear on a worksheet. You would have to write a VBA routine to accomplish that.
